# Concatenate char[] and uint32_t in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, concatenation, uint32

I want to concatenate a char[] with a uint32_t to get another char[] as result:

```
char word[] = "hi";
uint32_t = 33;

char result[] = "hi33"; //How can I get this ???
```

The goal is to assemble some data that can be passed to a `WriteData` method described [here](http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/CPPWindows) with the following signature...

```
bool WriteData(char *buffer, unsigned int nbChar);
```

Comment: Use `std::stringstream`.  Don't use character arrays.

Comment: `uint32_t = 33;` is a syntax error

Comment: If you must use a `char[]`, you'll need [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/)

Comment: Hi, I must use char[] because I am interested in the function WriteData of "SerialClass.h", used to write in serial port of arduino: http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/CPPWindows

Comment: Oh boy, look for a better library. That function should take a **`const`** `char*`. Which is easily returned from `std::string::c_str()`.

Comment: I am going to try with sprintf as **smead** said. I let you know when I finish. Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: it must be doing division by 10, getting modulus 10, subtracting '0' char value from it(then saving), repeating until last digit is computed.

Comment: @Sergio Looking at the definition of `WriteData` it passes the buffer parameter as the second argument to a [WriteFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747.aspx) call.  The second parameter to `WriteFile` is a pointer to constant data (`LPCVOID`).  As @iinspectable points out WriteData should take `const char *` but since it doesn't you could use `const_cast<>` to remove the `const`ness of `c_str()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write in the serial port of Arduino using that library you should do this:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    Serial* SP = new Serial("COM3");
    HDC dc = GetDC(NULL);
    char word[25];
    uint8_t n;
    uint32_t r, g, b;
    while (SP->IsConnected()) {
        n = sprintf_s(word,"%dr%dg%db\n",r,g,b);
        SP->WriteData(word, n-1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

sprintf_s returns the length of the buffer you want to write, yo can use this as the parameter of the WriteData function.

Answer (score 5):

You would do:

```
std::string word = "hi";
uint32_t num = 33;
std::string result = word + std::to_string(num);
```

(without the `std::` if you have `using namespace std`)

Ideally you would not use `char[]` because there's no reason to.

If necessary a `string` can be constructed from a `char[]`

```
char word[] = "hi";
std::string result {word};
```

Removing the `const` qualifier can be dangerous but if a method such as `WriteData` is known to be safe (i.e., does not modify the contents of its parameter) then it can be called like this

```
WriteData(const_cast<char *>(result.c_str()), result.length());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use std::string in this case, but when you go for char [] you can use:

```
sprintf( result, "%s%u", word, num );
```

In the case of using string you have several ways:
The first way is:

```
auto result = word + std::to_string(num);
```

The second way can be using stringstream:

```
ostringstream oss;
oss << word << num;
```

and result could be:

```
oss.str();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::ostringstream`:

```
static const char word[] = "Elephant";
std::ostringstream stream;
stream << word << 33;
std::string text;
text = stream.str();
```

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is:

```
std::string word = "hi";   
std::uint32_t num = 33;

auto result = word + std::to_string(num);
```